# how to stop PullToRefresh animation of ListView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, pull-to-refresh

I used [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) from `chrisbanes` to show refresh progress in my app.

I load data in AsyncTask, so I start refreshing by calling `mPullRefreshListView.setRefreshing();`
in `onPreExecute` method

and stop refreshing by 
calling `mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();`
 in `onPostExecute` method.

That works fine. But the problem happens when network down. Because I won`t use AsyncTask when network down any more, instead I load local cache.

I don`t want to show the `PullToRefresh` animations when refreshing if network down, but since it registered the `setOnRefreshListener`, every time when user pull down the ListView, it shows the refreshing animations, and never got disappear.

I tried to disable the animation by calling `mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();`, but it does`t help.

```
if (!Utils.isNetworkOn()) {
                if (mPullRefreshListView.isRefreshing())
                    mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();
            }
```

I feel very confused about this, anyone knows how to handle this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably hack it by setting the "theseChildsArePullable" (or whatever it's called) on the pullToRefresh to null when your network goes down and then re-instating it when the network is online. Haven't tried though.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` since Chris Bane's project is no longer maintained:

```android
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srl_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>

In fragment:
private void pullToRefreshForConfiguredList(View view) {

        mConfiguredSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.srl_layout);
        mConfiguredSwipeRefreshLayout
        .setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // call Method to be refreshed

if (mConfiguredSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
                        mConfiguredSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        mConfiguredSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.black,
                R.color.red, android.R.color.black, R.color.red);
    }
```

Comment: But there are not some complete tutorials about how to use that

Comment: Let me Google that for you http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-swiperefreshlayout-tutorial.html